# error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, docker, jenkins, build, msbuild

I am trying to build c# project with Jenkins and build.ps1 inside docker for the **FIRST** times.

Detail Error:

> C:\myproject\Properties\Resources.resx : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx
> file. Type in the data at line 123, position 5, cannot be loaded
> because it threw the following exception during construction: The
> specified module could not be found
> [C:\myproject\myproject.Config.csproj]

May I know why it happens? Any reason?

Update

this is resources.resx

```
 121  : <data name="config_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
 122  :   <value>..\Resources\config_icon.ico;System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
 123  : </data>
```

this is Config.csproj

```
 123  : <Reference Include="CommonServiceLocator, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=489b6accfaf20ef0, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
 124  :<HintPath>..\packages\CommonServiceLocator.2.0.4\lib\net46\CommonServiceLocator.dll</HintPath>
 125  :       </Reference>
```

I am not sure this line no in error message is really pointing the error or not.

Comment: A [Dev Community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1265927/msb3103-with-build-tools-under-docker.html) is open for this; if still facing this problem perhaps consider upvoting there.

Comment: @T2PS Check my updated answer. I used this docker file and working fine for me. Just check and test with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe some useful for u if u also having this issue. It took a week for me :(

**This error is because of server core, core cant recognizes that kind of format. Need to use another window.**

Here is ref link => [dotnet build fails](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7963#issuecomment-354538409)

**Update**

This is my latest docker file for this issue and working fine. take a look at it and ref if u want.

It needed to install not only **MSBuild tools** but also **Management Build tools**.

```
#Base Image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

#Copy Needed Folder
ADD ./setup c:/jenkins 
ADD ./jenkinsdata c:/jenkinsdata

#Jenkins
RUN ["msiexec.exe", "/i", "C:\\jenkins\\jenkins.msi", "/qn"]

#Java
RUN powershell start-process -filepath C:\jenkins\jre-8u251-windows-i586.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=c:\Java\jre1.8.0_91,/L,install64.log"

RUN set JAVA_HOME=""c:\\Java\\jre1.8.0_91\\"
RUN set PATH=%PATH%,%JAVA_HOME%\bin

# Install Chocolatey
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$env:ChocolateyUseWindowsCompression='false'; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
RUN powershell choco feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation

# Install Git
RUN powershell choco install git --allow-empty-checksums -y 

# Install DotNet 4.6.1
RUN powershell choco install netfx-4.6.1-devpack --allow-empty-checksums -y 

# Install MsBuild
RUN powershell choco install visualstudio2017buildtools --allow-empty-checksums -y 

# Install ManagementBuildTools
RUN powershell choco install visualstudio2017-workload-manageddesktopbuildtools --allow-empty-checksums -y 

# Delete files
RUN Powershell.exe -Command remove-item c:/jenkins –Recurse
```

Comment: Unfortunately choco is blacklisted in our environment, and the implied components/workloads from VSBT are already installed in our image. Not sure if the issue description of not using embedded icons in ResX will work given our build is using the NetFx ResGen.exe rather than dotnet, but will give that a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Properties Windows(Ctrl+W, P) in .resx file change persistence property to: "Embedded in .resx file" to resolve Problem.

if you use docker image to build your project in Linux system all resource name must be in lowercase [Related Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60973376/1181948)

Comment: I didn't see persistence property. May I know where it is?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and, in my case, the **path names were not exactly as the filesystem (case-sensitive). When building on Linux/ubuntu/docker**, dotnet resource embedder was not able to find the exact match in the local filesystem. The "file not found error" was solved using the exact same case on each path (folder & filenames). Apparently, the compiler is capable of changing '' to '/' when running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I used Azure DevOps to build a dotnet project.

**Issue:** The pipeline was sat to use ubuntu-latest agent. This led to the issue when I used `dotnet build Release`:

```
**/Properties/Resources.resx(0,0): Error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/**/resources/template.html'. at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding) at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.AddLinkedResource(String resxFilename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath, List`1 resources, String name, String value) at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.ParseData(String resxFilename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath, List`1 resources, Dictionary`2 aliases, XElement elem) at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResourceHandling.MSBuildResXReader.ReadResources(Stream s, String filename, Boolean pathsRelativeToBasePath)
```

**Cause:** It is related to application compatibility with the OS.

**Solution:** to the problem was, by changing vm agent from `ubuntu-latest` to `windows-latest`.